# Xamarin project fails to build in Visual Studio showing missing NuGets after opening from a different IDE

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.IOs project which has also got a NetStandard project that forms a solution together.

I normally use Visual Studio for Windows to develop my application. But when ever I open the same solution with a different IDE, say Visual Studio for Mac (to upload images to the project) then I get build errors in Visual Studio for Windows for the same solution sighting some missing NuGets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio for Windows OR Visual Studio for Mac as the normal IDE, then for some reason use a different IDE to open the same solution, then this sort of build errors would appear for some local IDE caching.

**How to fix this?**

- Quit all IDEs that hold reference to the solution
- Then delete the hidden local IDE cache directory found in the root of the solution (called **.vs**) Note that this is a hidden file

  [image]
- Delete the **bin** and **obj** directories in each project
- Open the solution in the IDE that the build failed
- Restore NuGet packages (if it's not set to happen on build)
- Build the solution (Now it would succeed!)

This had worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rizan's answer, here's a powershell script that would clear all folders generated (save it with the extension .ps1 and right click and select Run with powershell):

```
# Define files and directories to delete
$include = @("*.suo","*.user","*.cache","*.docstates","bin","obj","*.GhostDoc.xml",".vs")

# Define files and directories to exclude
$exclude = @()

$items = Get-ChildItem . -recurse -force -include $include -exclude $exclude

if ($items) {
    foreach ($item in $items) {
        Remove-Item $item.FullName -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Write-Host "Deleted" $item.FullName
    }
}

Write-Host "Press any key to continue . . ."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```